# How to influence fx:id Elements from other Controllers

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

I'm new in Java FX and have some basic understanding problems with controllers, FXML files and their interaction.

I am using Scenebuilder and tried something simple.
I have got a FXML file with just an AnchorPane and it is linked with the Controller class. It should be my main class to play around with those other FXML Controllers.

I have got a "Knopf" FXML which just includes a Button with its Controller "KnopfController"
And I have got a "Feld" FXML which includes a Textfield its Controller ist "FeldController".

Both "Knopf.FXML" and "Feld.FXML" are included in the Anchor Pane.

My Code looks like this:

```
package sample;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;

public class Controller {

@FXML
private AnchorPane Main;

@FXML
private FeldController feldController;

@FXML
private KnopfController knopfController;

public void textChange(MouseEvent event){
    //Hier Comes the Code
}
```

Now my Question is:

How can I interact between my Button (if it's pressed) and my TextField (that it should say "Hello" when the button is pressed?

Both the Button (fx:id="Knopf" in the Knopf.FXML) and the TextField (fx:id="Feld" in the Feld.FXML) should be useable for me.

How can I archive that?

I know I could use just both in an Controller but I want to practice the Interaction between Controllers and FXML files.

Comment: Ok I guess I understand it now.
I have to implement Methods inside the "Feld" Controller and the "Knopf" Controller class, so I can use it in my Main Controller Class.

Comment: Best way is to use an MVC (or similar) approach. Share a model with the different controllers and update/observe data in the model. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342864/applying-mvc-with-javafx. Another approach is just to pass a reference to the `Controller` to the `KnopfController`, so you can call `textChange()` in the button event handler, and then just define a method that updates the text field in `FeldController` and call it from the `textChange()` method.

Comment: Thank you I tried the second approach of yours.
I get a NullpointerException, where I use the textChange() method in the KnopfController.

I Just added @FXML Controller controller; to the KnopfController.

Can u tell me what I have to write to get it into the FXML file? Including it in the SceneBuilder is not the solution I guess.

Comment: Yeah, that won't work (there is nothing with `fx:id="controller"` in `Knopf.fxml`). You have to create a `setController(...)` method in `KnopfController` and call `knopfController.setController(this)` from the main controller's `initialize()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way is just to define the methods you need in each controller and call them from the event handler. In this case, your `KnopfController` will need to call the `textChange()` method in the main controller (so it needs a reference to the `Controller`), and then `textChange()` will call a method in the `FeldController`.

So you would do something like this:

```
public class FeldController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    public void updateText(String text) {
        textField.setText(text);
    }
}
```

`KnopfController` needs a reference to the "main controller", so it will need

```
public class KnopfController {

    private Controller mainController ;

    public void setMainController(Controller mainController) {
        this.mainController = mainController ;
    }

    // button handler:
    @FXML
    private void handleButtonClick(ActionEvent event) {
        mainController.textChange("Hello");
    }
}
```

And now your main controller wires it all together:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane Main;

    @FXML
    private FeldController feldController;

    @FXML
    private KnopfController knopfController;

    public void initialize() {
        knopfController.setMainController(this);
    }

    public void textChange(String newText){
        feldController.updateText(newText);
    }
}
```

---

While this works, the design problem here is that you have tightly coupled the controllers (e.g. your `KnopfController` depends on the `Controller` class, which to some extent works against the idea of factoring it out into a separate FXML-controller pair in the first place). A better approach is to share a data model among the controllers, and update/observe the model.

E.g.:

```
public class Model {

    private final StringProperty text = new SimpleStringProperty() ;

    public StringProperty textProperty() {
        return text ;
    }

    public final String getText() {
        return textProperty().get();
    }

    public final void setText(String text) {
        textProperty().set(text);
    }
}
```

and now the basic idea is to do

```
public class KnopfController {

    private Model model ;

    @FXML
    private void handleButton() {
        model.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

and

```
public class FeldController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    private Model model ;

    // ...
        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.textProperty());
    // ...
}
```

Of course, both these controllers need to have a reference to the same model instance for this to work, so you need to "inject" this into the controllers. You can do this just by creating `setModel()` methods and calling them:

```
public class KnopfController {

    private Model model ;

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
    }

    @FXML
    private void handleButton() {
        model.setText("Hello");
    }
}
```

and for `FeldController` you can do the binding when the model is set:

```
 public class FeldController {

    @FXML
    private TextField textField ;

    private Model model ;

    public void setModel(Model model) {
        this.model = model ;
        textField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.textProperty());
    }
}
```

Then your main controller just reduces to:

```
public class Controller {

    private Model model ;

    @FXML
    private FeldController feldController;

    @FXML
    private KnopfController knopfController;

    public void initialize() {
        model = new Model();
        knopfController.setModel(model);
        feldController.setModel(model);
    }
}
```

You can go one step further, and use a controller factory to provide the model to the controllers for you. I posted an example of doing that in a [github repo](https://github.com/james-d/EasyJavaFXDI). Note this is only proof-of-concept: to do DI like this you should probably use a framework for it - [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) provides a simple but flexible JavaFX DI framework (or you can use other, standard, frameworks such as Spring or Guice).

Comment: Wow mate thank you so much for your effort!

I will try to look at it. Read the fist part today and had problems with understanding  MVC and how to use it.(The Model part with creating a new Model)

Also it's the first time I got encountered with initialize() method and the setController Method. Hopefully I will get into it.

Will read into it. Hopefully I will refere back to you once fully understood.

Its a pitty It's not that simple like I thought and a simple thing is that complicated.